# Find all points on the surface where the tangentplane is parallel to the yz-plane

Tags: calculus

Find all points on the surface $g(x,y,z)=4x^2 -xyz-z^2=29$ where the tangentplane is parallel to the $yz$-plane

I know that in order for it to be parallel with the $yz$ plane I need (grad $g(x,y,z))=t\,\mathbf{i}$  so I got

$(8x-yz)\,\mathbf{i} -(xz)\,\mathbf{j} -(2z+xy)\,\mathbf{k} = t\,\mathbf{i}$ but I'm not sure what I'm actually trying to do or how to proceed next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $xz=0$ and $2z+xy=0$ since there is no term of $j$ or $k$ on the RHS.

Comment: ahh ok I see so first step would be to check  x=0 which gives z=0 so then I just try to find solutions for g(0,y,0)=29?

Comment: Yes, but g(0,y,0)=0=29 is absurd so you have to choose z=0.